# Theme generic file link in node template

Tags: entities

I want to change the text on a link to download a file in my node template. In **Manage Display** I have selected  **Generic File** as the formatter which outputs this

[image]

but I want to change it to this

[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: @Watergate Indeed can be marked as duplicate as the solutions are same, even though this question's about Manage Display page, and the dupe is about Views, both use "Generic File" formatter, and the solution is to override it or introduce a custom formatter.

Comment: @Beebee I undertand your point, therefore I think the title 'possible duplicate' is in it's place here. The solutions given in the linked answer are more extensive than the one currently given here.

Answer (score 0):

You can function theme_file_link() , you can change the file link title before html rendered for file link in your custom themes templete.php file.